# Synchronisation of settings

Tags: directoryopus

I'm looking for a way to synchronise my Directory Opus settings, across multiple machines. I've looked at the Backup and Restore settings offered by Opus, but they seem a little labour intensive. Ideally I'd like to sync the settings to a remote server (FTP, WebDAV).

Comment: Have you considered using [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)?

Comment: Using Puppet in what way?

Comment: The thought I had- which may not be a particularly good solution for Directory Opus- but you could put a puppet server on the main Directory Opus server, and a client on the others, write a [manifest](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/manifests.html) that covered [the files mentioned here](http://resource.dopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=10646) (or, at least, the ones that can / should be copied) and deploy that whenever you make changes. However, I'm putting this in a comment, rather than an answer, since (1) I'm not terribly familiar with Directory Opus, and (2) your problem appears to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article [How to backup or locate your Opus configuration](http://resource.dopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=7412)
describes how to locate the two folders that you need to synchronize :

> **Locating the config files by hand:**
>
> If you need to know where Directory Opus stores its configuration
>   data, for example to include it in automated backups made via a script
>   or third-party tool, then you should open an Opus window and type the
>   following aliases into the Location field:
>
> ```
> /dopusdata
> /dopusglobaldata
> ```
>
> They will take you to the appropriate configuration directories. **The
>   exact locations vary depending on your profile path, version of
>   Windows and whether Opus is in Shared or Private configuration mode.**
>
> There is some more configuration data under /dopuslocaldata but it's
>   things like the thumbnail cache and window sizes/positions and thus
>   probably not worth backing up.
>
> You may need to locate your configuration folders manually if you need
>   to do a backup in a situation where Opus will not start. (e.g. If Opus
>   won't start and you wish to try an uninstall + reinstall, the
>   uninstall would wipe your config and a manual backup is required to
>   preserve it.) Here are the usual locations:
>
> /dopusdata: 
>   `C:\Users\<Your Name>\AppData\Roaming\GPSoftware\Directory Opus`
>
> /dopusglobaldata: `C:\ProgramData\GPSoftware\Directory Opus`

Answer (score 1):

Let me recommend you [BT-Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) it's available for most platforms, it's secure and peer to peer. Just select the folder you want synchronized.
Within BT-Sync selecting the preference of the folders you want synchronized, will provide you with 2 Secret keys;

- The first key is for **Read and Write**: It allows you to propagate any changes made on that system. to all the other systems.
- The second key is **Read Only**: All changes made with the first key **R&W** will be taken in to account, but any changes made on that system, wont propagate.

The only thing you need to do is to go on your 2nd system or 3rd system if you want it offsite and be used as a remote server.

1. Install bt-sync
2. Select the folder(s)
3. Populate the secret(s).

in your case, 2 secrets for 2 folders.

```
/dopusdata
/dopusglobaldata
```

It's really easy to use. and your files will be transferred from all your online devices at the same time between them with P2P.

Keep me posted.

Comment: Sometimes I connect with corporate networks, so using BitTorrent is often inappropriate.

Comment: it's not torrent per-say, it's a separate software, made by bittorrent the organisation. The software is Named Sync.